# MySQL - Using where not exists returns null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out why a simple query returns null:

```
SELECT CardNo FROM BOOK_LOANS WHERE DueDate=DateReturned AND
NOT EXISTS
(SELECT CardNo FROM BOOK_LOANS WHERE DueDate<>DateReturned)
```

I've been learning about `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but cant seem to find any examples using both `WHERE` and `NOT EXISTS`. Is this there a better way to go about this?

My query works when i instead use `NOT IN` but i have to use `NOT EXISTS` in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT CardNo FROM BOOK_LOANS A WHERE A.DueDate=A.DateReturned AND
NOT EXISTS
(SELECT CardNo FROM BOOK_LOANS B WHERE B.CardNo = A.CardNo B.DueDate<>B.DateReturned)
```

Basically, you need to join the outer query with inner query on `CardNo` otherwise `NOT EXISTS` will return any record where dates do not match.

Comment: Works great! Thanks. Just missing the `AND` between `B.CardNo = A.CardNo B.DueDate<>B.DateReturned`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `NOT EXISTS` clause you must link subquery with the main query.

An example:

```
SELECT *
FROM persons p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'OTHER'
FROM persons p2
WHERE p.id <> p2.id AND p.city_id = p2.city_id)
```

In this query I want to extract all persons where not exists another person in the same city. So I linked my subquery table (persons p2) with main query table (persons p)

In your example, surely, exist two records with `DueDate<>DateReturned` so your query returns always NULL